# Instances of mutual parakaya pravesa

Tags: scripture, yoga

Parakaya pravesa is a well known in sanathan dharma in which a jiva can enter in to another person body.

So, it may also be possible that two persons can swap their Jivas.

But, are there any such instances in scriptures?

Comment: It's not a game in order do this the person be realized I believe any realized person seldom do this kind because it's normal for them 8 ma siddhi is just available to them they can use it only to show lord's greatness not otherwise if they use it otherwise they will be going down the spiritual path

Comment: I'm not sure if it is such an accepted fundamental fact as you seem to assume. It is more in the area of common folklore and legend, rather than scripturally authoritative doctrine.